# how to avoid triggering properties while debugging?

Tags: c#, debugging, properties

is there a way to prevent triggering of property getter code while watching variables in debug?
something in the style of the DebuggerStepThrough attribute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the DebuggerBrowsableAttribute

[DebuggerBrowsableAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerbrowsableattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

Tools\Options\Debugging\General\"Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls" - uncheck that box in VS.

Comment: Is there a way to do it on a single property?  For instance by using Attributes?

Comment: this definitely answers my question, however @jeff Cyr's answer matches my specific situation better - that's why I chose it. thanks!